# Eigenvalues of symmetric 2 by 2 matrix in terms of variables \

Tags: python

So given a symmetric matrix like of the form:

```py
[[a,c]
[c,b]]
```

One can get the eigenvalues with a general expression provided by the following function:

```py
def get_eigenvals(a,b,c):
    e1 = 0.5*(a + b + ((a-b)**2 + 4*c**2)**(1/2))
    e2 = 0.5*(a + b - ((a-b)**2 + 4*c**2)**(1/2))
    return(e1,e2)
```

But if I input `a`,`b` and `c` that contain variables, how could I get the eigenvalues in terms of the same variables? For example if I set `a = 5D`, `D` being the variable, how can I then have my eigenvalues returned as expressions containing `D`?

This is easy to implement in a program like Mathematica, but I'm wondering if there's a way of doing it in Python.

Comment: https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Comment: What is a "variable" in your program? You need to define that first.

Comment: the "variable" would effectively just be a symbol. I don't want to assign a value to it, but rather have the answer be expressed in terms of that symbol.